# No type for image in tinymce version 4

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I need to develop a small plugin for tinyMCE 4.0.
I have to show preview of image based on the input url.
I cannot figure out the type for image preview.

Is there anything like type="image"

```
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('uploadimage', function(editor, url) {
    // Adds a menu item to the Insert menu
    editor.addMenuItem('uploadimage', {
        text: 'Example plugin',
        context: 'insert',
        onclick: function() {

            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'TinyMCE site',
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                buttons: [{
                        text: 'Close',
                        onclick: 'close'
                    }],
                body: [

                    {
                        name: "path",
                        type: "textbox",
                        size: 40,
                        label: "File URL",

                    },
                    {
                        name: "fileList",
                        type: "listbox",
                        label: "Link list",
                        values: editor.settings.external_image_list_url,
                        onselect: function(e) {
                            this.parent().parent().find("#path").value(this.value());
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "fieldset",
                        type:"image"  //HERE I NEED TO PREVIEW IMAGE BUT THERE IS NO SUCH TYPE IMAGE
                    }
                ],
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet is to specify the type as "Container" and then set the HTML output manually with method "renderHtml" as can be seen in the documentation at:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.Container

On the right side of that page you get to see a list of all the available types. This could be extended obviously if you decide to code your own Image control.